# Creating a form on google app script and although I have added styling for mobile screen, it's not being applied in mobile view in the app script

Tags: html, css, google-apps-script

I want to create a form on google app script which is connected to the spreadsheet. everything works fine just that the mobile view for the deployed application on google script is not applying the styling i have created for small screens: @media only screen and (max-width: 768px). Although in svaing the code as html file and opening in browser in mobile view its working fine.

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      margin: 20px;
    }

    h2 {
      text-align: center;
    }

    label {
      display: block;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    input,
    select {
      width: 30%;
      padding: 8px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    #itemDetailsTable input,
    #itemDetailsTable select {
      width: 90%;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 8px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    table {
      width: 100%;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      margin-top: 15px;
    }

    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      padding: 8px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    input[type="button"] {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 4px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    input[type="button"]:hover {
      background-color: #45a049;
    }

    #EnquiryCaptureForm {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .logo-container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      margin-bottom: 20px; /* Add some space between logo and form */
    }

    /* Media query for mobile view */
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    width: 100%;
  }

  #EnquiryCaptureForm input,
  #EnquiryCaptureForm select {
    width: 90%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

    #itemDetailsTable input,
  #itemDetailsTable select {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  #itemDetailsTable td {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  #itemDetailsTable select {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  #itemDetailsTable input[type="number"],
  #itemDetailsTable input[type="text"] {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  #itemDetailsTable th,
  #itemDetailsTable td {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  #itemDetailsTable th {
    text-align: left;
  }
}
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="logo-container">
    <img src="https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/626/940/original/circle-logo-vector-templates.jpg" alt="Description" style="width: 200px; height: auto;">
  </div>

  <h2>Enquiry Capture Form</h2>
  <form id="EnquiryCaptureForm">
  <label for="referenceCode">Reference Code:</label>
  <input type="text" id="referenceCode" name="referenceCode" readonly>
    <br>

    <label for="pINumber">PI Number:</label>
    <select id="pINumber" name="pINumber" required>
    <option value="   ">  </option>
    <option value="To Be Made"> To Be Made </option>
    <option value="not Required"> Not Required </option>
    </select>

    <label for="clientName">Client Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="clientName" name="clientName" required>

    <label for="architectName">Architect Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="architectName" name="architectName" required>

    <label for="clientPhoneNumber">Client Phone Number:</label>
    <input type="text" id="clientPhoneNumber" name="clientPhoneNumber" required>
  

    <label for="architectPhoneNumber">Architect Phone Number:</label>
    <input type="text" id="architectPhoneNumber" name="architectPhoneNumber">


    <label for="clientmailid">Client Mail id:</label>
    <input type="mail" id="clientmailid" name="clientmailid" required>

    <label for="architectmailid">Architect Mail id:</label>
    <input type="mail" id="architectmailid" name="architectmailid">

    <label for="clientCompanyName">Client Company Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="clientCompanyName" name="clientCompanyName" required>

    <label for="referenceName">Reference Name :</label>
    <select id="referenceName" name="referenceName" required>
       <option value="   ">  </option>
      <option value="architect">Architect</option>
      <option value="walking">walking</option>
      <option value="online">Online</option>
      <option value="client">Client</option>
      <option value="management">Management</option>
      <option value="repeatclient">Repeat client</option>
      <option value="other">other</option>
    </select>

    <label for="referencepersonName">Reference Person Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="referencepersonName" name="referencepersonName" required>

    <label for="salesPersonName">Sales Person Name:</label>
    <select id="salesPersonName" name="salesPersonName" required>
      <option value="   ">  </option>
      <option value="anjali">Anjali</option>
      <option value="rupesh">Rupesh</option>
      <option value="sameer">Sameer</option>
      <option value="other">Other</option>
    </select>

    <label for="projectType">Project Type:</label>
    <select id="projectType" name="projectType" onchange="toggleOtherProjectType(this)" required>
       <option value="   ">  </option>
      <option value="home">Home</option>
      <option value="office">Office</option>
      <option value="other">Other</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="otherProjectType" name="otherProjectType" style="display: none;" placeholder="Enter custom project type">


    <label for="leadTime">Lead Time in days:</label>
    <input type="number" id="leadTime" name="leadTimeindays" required>


    <h3>Item Details</h3>

    <table id="itemDetailsTable">
      <tr>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Rate</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>GST (18%)</th> 
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>Remarks</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
            <select id="item1" name="item1" onchange="toggleOtherItemInput(1)">
            <option value="    ">    </option>   
            <option value="Arg_HB-28000">Argon_HB-28000</option>
            <option value="Ath_MB-14000">Athens_MB-14000</option>
            <option value="other">Other</option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" id="otherItem1" name="otherItem1" style="display:none;" placeholder="Enter custom item">
            </td>
          <td><input type="number" id="rate1" name="rate1" oninput="calculateTotal(1)"></td>
          <td><input type="number" id="qty1" name="qty1" oninput="calculateTotal(1)"></td>
          <td><input type="number" id="gst1" name="gst1" readonly></td>
          <td><input type="number" id="total1" name="total1" readonly></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="remarks1" name="remarks1"></td>
          <td><input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete-btn" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>
       </tr>
       </table> 
     
    <br>

    <input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow()">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm()">
  </form>

  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var table = document.getElementById("itemDetailsTable");

  // Add an event listener for the delete button click event
  table.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    if (e.target.tagName === "INPUT" && e.target.classList.contains("delete-btn")) {
      deleteRow(e.target);
    }
  });
});

function deleteRow(button) {
  var row = button.closest('tr'); // Find the closest parent 'tr' element
  var table = row.parentNode; // Get the table that contains the row
  var rowIndex = row.rowIndex;

  // Ensure there are more than one rows before allowing deletion
  if (table.rows.length > 1) {
    table.deleteRow(rowIndex);
  } else {
    alert("Cannot delete the only row");
  }
}

 function toggleOtherProjectType(select) {
    var otherProjectTypeInput = document.getElementById('otherProjectType');
    if (select.value === 'other') {
      otherProjectTypeInput.style.display = 'block';
      otherProjectTypeInput.required = true;
    } else {
      otherProjectTypeInput.style.display = 'none'; 
      otherProjectTypeInput.required = false;
    }
  }

  function toggleOtherItemInput(rowNumber) {
    console.log("Toggling other item input for row: ", rowNumber); // This should log every time you change the selection.
  var itemSelect = document.getElementById('item' + rowNumber);
  var otherItemInput = document.getElementById('otherItem' + rowNumber);
  if(itemSelect.value === 'other') {
    otherItemInput.style.display = 'inline'; // Show the text input
  } else {
    otherItemInput.style.display = 'none'; // Hide the text input
    otherItemInput.value = ''; // Clear any text that was entered
  }
}


      function generateUniqueCode() {
  var uniqueCode = '';
  var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'; // Alphabets for the code
  var digits = '0123456789'; // Digits for the code

  // Generating one random alphabet character
  var randomChar = characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length));
  uniqueCode += randomChar;

  // Generating four random digits
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var randomDigit = digits.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * digits.length));
    uniqueCode += randomDigit;
  }

  return uniqueCode;
}

    function displayUniqueCode() {
      var uniqueResponseCode = generateUniqueCode();
      document.getElementById('referenceCode').value = uniqueResponseCode;
    }

    // Function to execute when the page loads
    window.onload = displayUniqueCode;

    function updateTotalAndGST(row) {
    var rate = parseFloat(row.querySelector('[name^="rate"]').value) || 0;
    var qty = parseFloat(row.querySelector('[name^="qty"]').value) || 0;

    var totalAmount = rate * qty;
    var gstAmount = totalAmount * 0.18;
    var totalWithGST = totalAmount + gstAmount;

    row.querySelector('[name^="gst"]').value = gstAmount.toFixed(2);
    row.querySelector('[name^="total"]').value = totalWithGST.toFixed(2);
  }

   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      var table = document.getElementById("itemDetailsTable");

      // Add an event listener for the delete button click event
      table.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        if (e.target.tagName === "INPUT" && e.target.classList.contains("delete-btn")) {
          deleteRow(e.target);
        }
      });
    });

    function addRow() {
      var table = document.getElementById("itemDetailsTable");
      var rowCount = table.rows.length;

      var newRow = table.insertRow(rowCount);

      var cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
      var cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
      var cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
      var cell4 = newRow.insertCell(3);
      var cell5 = newRow.insertCell(4);
      var cell6 = newRow.insertCell(5);
      var cell7 = newRow.insertCell(6);
      // var cell8 = newRow.insertCell(7);
      // var cell9 = newRow.insertCell(8);

cell1.innerHTML = '<select id="item' + rowCount + '" name="item' + rowCount + '" onchange="toggleOtherItemInput(' + rowCount + ')">' +
      '<option value="    ">    </option>' +  
      '<option value="Arg_HB-28000">Argon_HB-28000</option>' +
      '<option value="Ath_MB-14000">Athens_MB-14000</option>' +
           '<option value="other">Other</option>' +
      '</select>' + // Ensure the '+' operator is correctly used to concatenate the next line
      '<input type="text" id="otherItem' + rowCount + '" name="otherItem' + rowCount + '" style="display:none;" placeholder="Enter custom item">';     
      cell2.innerHTML = '<input type="number" id="rate' + rowCount + '" name="rate' + rowCount + '" oninput="calculateTotal(' + rowCount + ')">';
      cell3.innerHTML = '<input type="number" id="qty' + rowCount + '" name="qty' + rowCount + '" oninput="calculateTotal(' + rowCount + ')">';
      cell4.innerHTML = '<input type="number" id="gst' + rowCount + '" name="gst' + rowCount + '" readonly>';
      cell5.innerHTML = '<input type="number" id="total' + rowCount + '" name="total' + rowCount + '" readonly>';
      cell6.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="remarks' + rowCount + '" name="remarks' + rowCount + '">';
      cell7.innerHTML = '<input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete-btn" onclick="deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode)">'; //Pass the current row to the deleteRow function

      if (rowCount > 1) {
        var deleteButton = document.createElement("input");
        deleteButton.type = "button";
        deleteButton.value = "Delete";
        deleteButton.classList.add("delete-btn");
        deleteButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
          deleteRow(deleteButton);
        });
        cell9.appendChild(deleteButton);
      } else {
        cell9.innerHTML = ''; // No delete button for the first row
      }
    }

     function toggleOtherItemInput(rowNumber) {
  var itemSelect = document.getElementById('item' + rowNumber);
  var otherItemInput = document.getElementById('otherItem' + rowNumber);
  if(itemSelect.value === 'other') {
    otherItemInput.style.display = 'inline'; // Show the text input
  } else {
    otherItemInput.style.display = 'none'; // Hide the text input
    otherItemInput.value = ''; // Clear any text that was entered
  }
}

    function calculateTotal(rowNumber) {
    var rate = parseFloat(document.getElementById('rate' + rowNumber).value) || 0;
    var qty = parseFloat(document.getElementById('qty' + rowNumber).value) || 0;
    
    var totalAmount = rate * qty;
    var gstAmount = totalAmount * 0.18; // Calculate GST (18%)
    var totalWithGST = totalAmount + gstAmount; // Add GST to the total amount

    document.getElementById('total' + rowNumber).value = totalWithGST.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('gst' + rowNumber).value = gstAmount.toFixed(2); // Display GST in the GST column
   }

    function submitForm() {
      // Fetch data from the form
      var referenceCode = document.getElementById('referenceCode').value;
      var pINumber = document.getElementById('pINumber').value;
      var clientName = document.getElementById('clientName').value;
      var architectName = document.getElementById('architectName').value;
      var clientPhoneNumber = document.getElementById('clientPhoneNumber').value;
      var architectPhoneNumber = document.getElementById('architectPhoneNumber').value;
      var clientmailid = document.getElementById('clientmailid').value;
      var architectmailid = document.getElementById('architectmailid').value;
      var clientCompanyName = document.getElementById('clientCompanyName').value;
      var referenceName = document.getElementById('referenceName').value;
      var referencepersonName = document.getElementById('referencepersonName').value;
      var salesPersonName = document.getElementById('salesPersonName').value;
      var projectType =document.getElementById('projectType').value;
      var leadTime =document.getElementById('leadTime').value;
      var projectTypeValue;
      var projectTypeSelect = document.getElementById('projectType');
      if (projectTypeSelect.value === 'other') {
      projectTypeValue = document.getElementById('otherProjectType').value;
     } else {
    projectTypeValue = projectTypeSelect.value;
    }

    if (clientmailid.trim() !== "") {
      // Validate email format
      var emailRegex = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;
      if (!emailRegex.test(clientmailid)) {
        alert("Please enter valid email addresses for Client and Architect.");
        return;
      }
    } else {
      // If client email is empty, set it to "NA"
      clientmailid = "NA";
    }


      // Validate phone number format and range using regular expression
      var phoneRegex = /^[6-9]\d{9}$/;
      if (!phoneRegex.test(clientPhoneNumber)) {
        alert("Please enter valid phone number");
        return;
      }


      var clientPhoneNum = parseInt(clientPhoneNumber);
      var architectPhoneNum = parseInt(architectPhoneNumber);
      if (clientPhoneNum < 5999999999 || clientPhoneNum > 9999999999 ) {
        alert("Please enter valid phone number.");
        return;
      }

      // Fetch item details from the table
      var itemDetails = [];
      var table = document.getElementById('itemDetailsTable');
    for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    var row = table.rows[i];
    var itemSelect = row.cells[0].getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
    var item = itemSelect.value;
    if(item === 'other') {
      item = row.cells[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value; // Get the value from the text input
    }
        var rate = row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
        var qty = row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value
        if (!clientName || !item || !rate || !qty) {
        alert("Please fill in Client Name, Item, Rate, and Qty for all rows before submitting the form.");
        return;
      }
        var gst = row.cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value; //extracted value of gst calculated
        var total = row.cells[4].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
        var remarks = row.cells[5].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;

        itemDetails.push({
          item: item,
          rate: rate,
          qty: qty,
          gst:gst, //added gst to the itemDetails object
          total: total,
          remarks: remarks
        });
      }

      // Create a FormData object to send to the server
      var formData = {
        referenceCode: referenceCode,
        pINumber:pINumber,
        clientName:clientName,
        architectName:architectName,
        clientPhoneNumber:clientPhoneNumber,
        architectPhoneNumber:architectPhoneNumber,
        clientmailid:clientmailid,
        architectmailid:architectmailid,
        clientCompanyName:clientCompanyName,
        referenceName:referenceName,
        referencepersonName:referencepersonName,
        salesPersonName:salesPersonName,
        projectType:projectType,
        leadTime:leadTime,
        itemDetails:itemDetails,
      };

        // Update formData object to include projectTypeValue
        formData.projectType = projectTypeValue;

       // Use google.script.run to call the server-side function
         google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(handleSuccess)
        .processForm(formData, itemDetails, table.rows.length - 1);
    }

     // Callback function to handle success
      function handleSuccess(response) {
      alert("Thanks For the Order");
     // reload the page rather than reset so that the reference Code is regerated which was not he case earlier.
     document.getElementById("EnquiryCaptureForm").reset();
      //location.reload(); do this when we have a static url so reload back to the page.
     }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Code.gs:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

 // This function is called when the form is submitted
function processForm(formData, itemDetails) {
  var sheetId = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId);

 // Add timestamp to the first column
  var timestamp = new Date();

  // Add data to the spreadsheet using appendRow for formData and the first itemDetail
sheet.appendRow([
  timestamp,
  formData.referenceCode,
  formData.pINumber,
  formData.clientName,
  formData.architectName,
  formData.clientPhoneNumber,
  formData.architectPhoneNumber,
  formData.clientmailid,
  formData.architectmailid,
  formData.clientCompanyName,
  formData.referenceName,
  formData.referencepersonName,
  formData.salesPersonName,
  formData.projectType,
  formData.leadTime,
  itemDetails.length > 0 ? itemDetails[0].item : "",
  itemDetails.length > 0 ? itemDetails[0].rate : "",
  itemDetails.length > 0 ? itemDetails[0].qty : "",
  itemDetails.length > 0 ? itemDetails[0].gst : "", //add gst to the sheet
  itemDetails.length > 0 ? itemDetails[0].total : "",
  itemDetails.length > 0 ? itemDetails[0].remarks : "", // Use correct index
  "" // Add an empty column for deleteButton
]);

// Add multiple rows for the remaining Item Details data
for (var i = 1; i < itemDetails.length; i++) {
  var itemDetail = itemDetails[i];
  sheet.appendRow([
    timestamp,
    formData.referenceCode,
    formData.pINumber,
    formData.clientName,
    formData.architectName,
    formData.clientPhoneNumber,
    formData.architectPhoneNumber,
    formData.clientmailid,
    formData.architectmailid,
    formData.clientCompanyName,
    formData.referenceName,
    formData.referencepersonName,
    formData.salesPersonName,
    formData.projectType,
    formData.leadTime,
    itemDetail.item,
    itemDetail.rate,
    itemDetail.qty,
    itemDetail.gst, //add gst to the sheet
    itemDetail.total,
    itemDetail.remarks, // Use correct index
    "" // Add an empty column for deleteButton
  ]);
}




  return "Form submitted successfully!";
}
```

Expected layout:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Actual google app script deployed mobile view:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

And no its is not because of the table at the bottom, it is being properly being viewed in the expected image just it is not visible because I will have to scroll.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iv3AI.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuzNO.png

Answer (score 0):

You should add meta tags with the HtmlOutput class: - [HtmlOutput.addMetaTag()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#detailed-documentation)

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: Have you gone to the link.  There is not much more to say.